# Limit which google map pins show on load

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I inherited some code and am stuck. On load it shows all years I only want it to show markers that have the year 2018. There is a jQuery slider that selects year but it loads all year's pins when the map loads. Thought I'd try here while searching the web to solve/learn this. This is only part of the code, but I believe it is the part that dictates what is shown on load.

```
function resizeMarker_Div() {
jQuery('.map-content-div').each(function() {
    var height = jQuery(this).height();
    var imgCover = jQuery(this).prev(); 
    imgCover.height(height);
});
}

resizeMarker_Div();


var infoWindow;
function initMap() {
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(34.4857537,-111.3747484);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
   addMarker(markers1[i]);
}
}
function addMarker(marker) {
var mylatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[0], marker[1]);
var category = marker[4];
var title = marker[2];
var content = marker[5];
var year = marker[3];


marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mylatLng,
    title: title,
    category: category,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    year: year

});

gmarkers1.push(marker1);
```

Comment: Do you want to show only one marker for 2018?

Comment: well, i want to show all wordpress posts that year = 2018

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: like a link? http://mountainviewmedia.com/fann-contracting/project-map/

Comment: see on page load, all markets, change the slider year, only that year's markers.

Comment: No, like a [mcve], specifically, **not** (just) a link to a page that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the markers to appear on page load, set their `visible` property to `false` when you create them (in your `addMarker` function).

```
function addMarker(marker) {
  var mylatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[0], marker[1]);
  var category = marker[4];
  var title = marker[2];
  var content = marker[5];
  var year = marker[3];

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mylatLng,
    title: title,
    category: category,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    year: year,
    visible: false  // <------------------------ add this
  });

  gmarkers1.push(marker1);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/40qhqj5e/)

**code snippet:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var handle = jQuery("#custom-handle");
  var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  var nmarkers = new Array();

  jQuery('#slider-filter').slider({
    range: false,
    min: 1999,
    max: 2018,
    step: 1,
    value: year,
    //

    //
    create: function() {
      handle.text(jQuery(this).slider("value"));
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      jQuery("#year-selected").val(ui.value);
      handle.text(ui.value);
      jQuery('').each(function() {
        //
        jQuery(this).prop("checked", true);
      });
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      handle.text(ui.value);
      jQuery("#year-selected").val(ui.value);
      var year = ui.value;
      var plus = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        //changed from <= to == to only show year slider is on now
        if (marker.year == year) {
          marker.setVisible(true);
          marker.setMap(map);

          infoWindow.close();
        } else {
          plus++;
          marker.setVisible(false);
          infoWindow.close();
        }

      }
      if (plus === markers1.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
          marker = gmarkers1[i];
          // set to false to hide blank years
          marker.setVisible(false);
        }
      }

    }

  });
  jQuery("#year-selected").val(jQuery("#slider-filter").slider("value"));
  // jQuery("#year-selected").val(jQuery("1999"));

  jQuery("#prev").click(function() {
    var s = jQuery("#slider-filter"),
      val = s.slider("value"),
      step = s.slider("option", "step");
    s.slider("value", val - step);
    jQuery('.categories').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
  });
  jQuery("#next").click(function() {
    var s = jQuery("#slider-filter"),
      val = s.slider("value"),
      step = s.slider("option", "step");
    s.slider("value", val + step);
    jQuery('.categories').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
  });
  jQuery('.filter-slider').click(function() {
    jQuery('.filter-slider .btn').css('opacity', '1');
    jQuery('.filter-slider #slider-filter').css('opacity', '1');
  });
  jQuery('.filter-slider #slider-filter').click(function() {
    jQuery('.filter-slider .btn').css('opacity', '1');
    jQuery('.filter-slider #slider-filter').css('opacity', '1');
  });
  jQuery('.filter-slider #slider-filter #custom-handle').click(function() {
    jQuery('.filter-slider .btn').css('opacity', '1');
    jQuery('.filter-slider #slider-filter').css('opacity', '1');
  });
  jQuery('.filter-slider .btn').click(function() {
    jQuery('.filter-slider .btn').css('opacity', '1');
    jQuery('.filter-slider #slider-filter').css('opacity', '1');
  });
  //joes
  //jQuery(' #slider-filter #custom-handle').click(function(){
  //        jQuery(' #slider-filter #custom-handle').css('opacity','0');
  //        jQuery(' #slider-filter #custom-handle').css('opacity','1');
  //    });


});
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];

var markers1 = [
  [34.549971, -112.446127,
    "fda",
    "2018",
    "Utility Infrastructure",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [33.3061605, -111.8412502,
    "Chandler, AZ",
    "2010",
    "Material Supply",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.638156, -112.41339,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2017",
    "Materials Hauling",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.62297, -112.397734,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2013",
    "Utility Infrastructure",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.538685, -112.477651,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2015",
    "Utility Infrastructure",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.527217, -112.462149,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2012",
    "Utility Infrastructure",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.560211, -112.385359,
    "Yavapai Hills, AZ",
    "2006",
    "Private Development",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [33.386942, -112.863026,
    "Palo Verde, AZ",
    "2012",
    "Private Development",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.552547, -112.406389,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2017",
    "Private Development",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.627891, -112.40366,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2016",
    "Private Development",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.632133, -111.831678,
    "I-17 near McGuireville, AZ",
    "2016",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.531492, -112.446035,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2016",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.785024, -112.424645,
    "Chino Valley, AZ",
    "2008",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.573106, -112.480707,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2012",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [33.521041, -113.067333,
    "I-10 Burnt Well Rest Area",
    "2015",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.1862813, -112.1345168,
    "I-17 Sunset Point Rest Area",
    "2013",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [32.730905, -113.716097,
    "I-10 near Dateland, AZ",
    "2017",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.20517, -112.760672,
    "South of Yarnell, AZ",
    "2016",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [36.061658, -112.109187,
    "Grand Canyon South Rim, AZ",
    "1999",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.514648, -112.04803,
    "Hwy 169, AZ",
    "2011",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.543276, -112.459697,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2005",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.496562, -112.446034,
    "Prescott, AZ",
    "2014",
    "Specialty Projects",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.959335, -112.133375,
    "Grand Canyon Airport, Tusayan, AZ",
    "2016",
    "Airport",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.992137, -113.81564,
    "Grand Canyon West, AZ",
    "2011",
    "Airport",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.957506, -112.141376,
    "Grand Canyon Airport, Tusayan, AZ",
    "2016",
    "Airport",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.123791, -109.318721,
    "Springerville, AZ",
    "2013",
    "Airport",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.136588, -111.672924,
    "Flagstaff Pulliam Airport",
    "2017",
    "Airport",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.904668, -113.94333,
    "Grand Canyon West, AZ",
    "2014",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.160572, -111.282308,
    "I-40 near Twin Arrows Casino, AZ",
    "2017",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.162275, -113.676033,
    "I-40 near Seligman, AZ",
    "2016",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.170003, -113.524763,
    "I-40 near Seligman, AZ",
    "2017",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [35.229376, -112.234586,
    "I-40 near Williams, AZ",
    "2017",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.742607, -111.686426,
    "I-17 near Village of Oak Creek, AZ",
    "2013",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.474036, -112.020904,
    "I-17 near Arcosanti, AZ",
    "2014",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [34.175888, -112.133023,
    "I-17 Black Canyon City, AZ",
    "2017",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [33.999509, -112.133472,
    "I-17 Black Canyon City, AZ",
    "2017",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [33.6307305, -113.7676805,
    "I-10 New Hope, AZ",
    "2016",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
  [32.813526, -113.507267,
    "I-10 near Dateland, AZ",
    "2013",
    "Highway and Transportation",
    "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'></div>",
  ],
];

function resizeMarker_Div() {
  jQuery('.map-content-div').each(function() {
    var height = jQuery(this).height();
    var imgCover = jQuery(this).prev();
    imgCover.height(height);
  });
}

resizeMarker_Div();


var infoWindow;
var map;

function initMap() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(34.4857537, -111.3747484);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,

  };

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers1[i]);
  }
}

function addMarker(marker) {
  var mylatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[0], marker[1]);
  var category = marker[4];
  var title = marker[2];
  var content = marker[5];
  var year = marker[3];


  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mylatLng,
    title: title,
    category: category,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    year: year,
    visible: false

  });

  gmarkers1.push(marker1);

  // Marker click listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
    return function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(content);
      //Client asked for infoWindow to be unclickable so the next line was commented out
      //infoWindow.open(map, marker1);
      resizeMarker_Div();
    }
  })(marker1, content));
}

function slider_change() {
  var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  jQuery('#slider-filter').slider({
    value: year
  });

  jQuery('.filter-slider .btn').css('opacity', '0.5');
  jQuery('.filter-slider #slider-filter').css('opacity', '0.5');

  var categories_name = new Array();

  jQuery('.categories').each(function() {
    //was false
    if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
      categories_name.push(jQuery(this).val());
    }
  });

  var plus = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (jQuery.inArray(marker.category, categories_name) != -1) {
      //was true
      marker.setVisible(true);
      marker.setMap(map);

      infoWindow.close();
    }
    // Categories don't match 
    else {
      plus++;
      marker.setVisible(false);
      infoWindow.close();
    }
  }
  if (plus === markers1.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
      marker = gmarkers1[i]; //was true
      marker.setVisible(true);
      marker.setMap(map);
    }
  }
}
//

initMap();

function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'none')
    e.style.display = 'block';

}

function toggle_visibility2(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-plugin-settings-css' href='http://mountainviewmedia.com/fann-contracting/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/css/settings.css?ver=5.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="filter-slider">
  <h2 class="slider-title">See Fann Projects Through The Years</h2>
  <h3 class="slider-subtitle">(Move slider to see all projects through the last 20 years)</h3>
  <input type="hidden" name="year-selected" id="year-selected" size="4" readonly>
  <button class="btn btn-prev" name="prev" id="prev" value="prev" onclick="toggle_visibility('custom-handle'); toggle_visibility2('custom-handle2');"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left">&lt;</i></button>
  <div id="slider-filter" onmousedown="toggle_visibility('custom-handle'); toggle_visibility2('custom-handle2');">
    <!-- div id="custom-handle2" style="display:block;" class="trick" onmousedown="toggle_visibility('custom-handle'); toggle_visibility2('custom-handle2');">ALL</div -->
    <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle" style="display:none;"></div>


  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-next" name="next" id="next" value="next" onclick="toggle_visibility('custom-handle'); toggle_visibility2('custom-handle2');"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right">&gt;</i></button>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="custom-handle"></div>
<div id="custom-handle2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `markers` data has the year within, as it appears to have, then you could try:

```
for( i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++ ) {
    var mkr=markers1[i];
    if( parseInt( mkr[3] )==2018 )addMarker( mkr );
}
```

Looking further at this I realise that the above would not really suit the situation as it will only load the markers for 2018 so it would be better to initially set the visibility of all markers to none ( in the `addmarker` function ) regardless of whether or not they are from the current year and then explicitly change that property for any marker from the current year. The `jQuery` slider code targets the visibility property of the marker which is why all markers must be added to the map initially.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google maps - display markers for year on load</title>
        <script>
            /* 
                configure these options to suit
                -------------------------------
                @var: clickable
                @type: Boolean
                @description: display infowindow or not when marker is clicked


                @var: draggable
                @type: Boolean
                @description: allow markers to be dragged

                @var: limityear
                @type: Boolean
                @description: Limits initial display of markers to the current year. 
                                All markers are added regardless but visibility of
                                markers is affected. Set as `true` to display current
                                year or `false` to display all.

                @var: hide
                @type: Boolean
                @description: This controls whether or not markers are initially hidden
                                or not. Set to `true` to hide markers not from this year
                                or `false` to display all.

            */
            var clickable=true; 
            var draggable=false;
            var limityear=true;
            var hide=true;


            var markers = [];
            var infoWindow,map,latlng,options,marker,bounds;

            function initMap(){
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( 34.4857537, -111.3747484 );
                options = {
                    zoom: 7,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );

                bounds.extend( latlng );

                var addmarker=function( mkr ){
                    latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( mkr[0], mkr[1] );

                    var title=mkr[2];
                    var category=mkr[4];
                    var year=mkr[3];
                    var content=mkr[5];
                    /*

                        Add marker for each location found in source
                        data array. Set the visibility to none initially
                        for each marker.

                    */
                    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        title: [ title, category, year ].join( String.fromCharCode(10) ),
                        category: category,
                        content:content,
                        map: map,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        year: year,
                        draggable:draggable,
                        visible:!hide /* Hide all markers - dependant upon variable `hide` - can be changed via querystring */
                    });
                    markers.push( marker );
                    bounds.extend( latlng );
                    /*
                        If the year for construction is the current year, set the visibility
                        of the marker to true. The jQuery slider affects this parameter of the
                        marker.
                    */
                    if( limityear && parseInt( year )==( new Date().getFullYear() ) ) marker.setVisible( true );


                    if( clickable ){/* change the `clickable` variable to display infowindow */
                        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function( event ){
                            infoWindow.setContent( this.content );
                            infoWindow.open( map, this );
                        }.bind( marker ) );
                    }                   
                }

                /* add markers ~ iterate through source data*/
                markers1.forEach( function( mkr ){
                    addmarker.call( this, mkr );
                });

                map.fitBounds( bounds );
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            var markers1 = [
                    [34.549971,
                     -112.446127,
                     "fda",
                     "2018",
                     "Utility Infrastructure",
                     "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'><div class='map-image-div' style = 'width:155px;min-height:100px; float:right;'><img src='http://mountainviewmedia.com/fann-contracting/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2118-pic1-150x150.jpg'style='width: 100%;height: 100%;'></div><div class='map-content-div' style =  'width:165px;min-height:100px; float:left; word-wrap:break-word;'><table border='1' style='min-height:150px;'><tr><td  style='padding:2px 4px;' colspan='2' align='center'><strong>Prescott Resort Casino Site Improvements</strong></td></tr><tr style=' vertical-align:top;'><td style='padding:2px 4px;'><strong>Location:</strong></td><td style='padding:2px 4px;'>fda</td></tr><tr style=' vertical-align:top;'><td style='padding:2px 4px;'><strong>Budget:</strong></td><td style='padding:2px 4px;'>fda</td></tr><tr style=' vertical-align:top;'><td style='padding:2px 4px;'><strong>For Whom:</strong></td><td style='padding:2px 4px;'>Yavapai Tribe</td></tr><tr><td style='padding:2px 4px;' colspan='2' align='center'><a href='http://mountainviewmedia.com/fann-contracting/ds_projects/test-post-2018/'>More Information >> </a></td></tr></table></div>",
                    ],
                    [33.3061605,
                     -111.8412502,
                     "Chandler, AZ",
                     "2010",
                     "Material Supply",
                     "<div style='width:320px; display:inline-block; padding:-15px;'><div class='map-image-div' style = 'width:155px;min-height:100px; float:right;'><img src='http://mountainviewmedia.com/fann-contracting/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/1000ISS-pic1-150x150.jpg'style='width: 100%;height: 100%;'></div><div class='map-content-div' style =  'width:165px;min-height:100px; float:left; word-wrap:break-word;'><table border='1' style='min-height:150px;'><tr><td  style='padding:2px 4px;' colspan='2' align='center'><strong>Hot Coated Chips Production</strong></td></tr><tr style=' vertical-align:top;'><td style='padding:2px 4px;'><strong>Location:</strong></td><td style='padding:2px 4px;'>Chandler, AZ</td></tr><tr style=' vertical-align:top;'><td style='padding:2px 4px;'><strong>Budget:</strong></td><td style='padding:2px 4px;'>$5,58,000</td></tr><tr style=' vertical-align:top;'><td style='padding:2px 4px;'><strong>For Whom:</strong></td><td style='padding:2px 4px;'>International Surfacing Systems</td></tr><tr><td style='padding:2px 4px;' colspan='2' align='center'><a href='http://mountainviewmedia.com/fann-contracting/ds_projects/hot-coated-chips-production/'>More Information >> </a></td></tr></table></div>",
                    ]
                    /* remaining data truncated for demo */
                ];
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBq6g18AQTdyQAH8woFYApo9VMdJzE04tA&callback=initMap'></script>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you have any questions just add a comment